# ngHide on model change

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I have the following spinner,

```
<div id="spinningSquaresG" ng-model="ajaxrequest"  ng-show="{{ajaxrequest}}">
<div id="spinningSquaresG_1" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_2" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_3" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_4" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_5" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_6" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_7" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
<div id="spinningSquaresG_8" class="spinningSquaresG">
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

In my controller I have set `$scope.ajaxrequest = false;` so the spinner is correctly hidden (if I set it ajaxrequest=true it appears, so I suppose there is no problem on that). Inside my controller I have a function that makes an ajax request, I want to show the spinner when the request starts and hide it when the request finishes. So I have:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
              $scope.ajaxrequest = true;
              console.log($scope.ajaxrequest);
        });

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
              $scope.ajaxrequest = false;
              console.log($scope.ajaxrequest);
        });
```

As I can see from the console the ajaxrequest value is changing correctly before and after the request. The problem is that the spinner does not appear. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using JQuery to trigger the change to `ajaxrequest` so angular has no idea that anything has changed. You could make a call to `scope.$apply()` after changing ajaxrequest to inform angular of the change but it would be much better to do this without JQuery.

Take a look at the documentation on interceptors for an example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I added `scope.$apply()` to ajaxStart and ajaxStop and it works, thank you. But does angular's `$http`service has something similar to ajaxStart/ajaxStop?

Comment: Yes, http interceptors as rob mentioned and linked to above are similar in function.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ng-show="ajaxrequest"` instead of `ng-show="{{ajaxrequest}}"`. `ng-show` takes an expression already, so the braces are not necessary.

Comment: I tried it, it shows the spinner, but when the `ajaxrequest`change back to false the spinner does not hide.